# can anyone tell whats wrong with my mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Can any one help me to figure out the problem in my query

```
$this->db->from('rac_details');
$this->db->join('vehicle_details','vehicle_details.id=rac_details.vehicle_id');
if($_SESSION['from_date']!=""){
         $this->db->where('from_date>=',$_SESSION['from_date']);
}
$query = $this->db->get('');
$rowcount = $query->num_rows();
return $rowcount;
```

i am getting error like this

> ## A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 1064
>
> You
>   have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
>   to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
>   '1455566400' at line 4
>
> SELECT *
>
> FROM (`rac_details`) JOIN `vehicle_details` ON
>   `vehicle_details`.`id`=`rac_details`.`vehicle_id` WHERE `from_date>=`
>   1455566400

Comment: what is the format of `from_date` column in your table? `timestamp` of `dattime`?

Comment: i have setit as bigint

Comment: `$this->db->where('from_date >=',$_SESSION['from_date']);` try it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$this->db->select(*); # Added
$this->db->from('rac_details');
$this->db->join('vehicle_details','vehicle_details.id=rac_details.vehicle_id');
if(!empty($_SESSION['from_date']))
{
    $from_date = $_SESSION['from_date']; # Added
    $this->db->where('tableName.from_date >=' , $from_date); # Improved
    # Add table name in above line
}
$query = $this->db->get();
$rowcount = $query->num_rows();
return $rowcount;
```

Comment: No need to add * in select function :p